# Google Ad's not sizing properly in div

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I have some google ads that I am placing inside a bootstrap sidebar, they have plenty of room veritcally but they are automaticcal resizing themselves to small banner ads. Here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <aside class="sidebar">
         <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Sponsors and Partners</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

         <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
           <!-- SHIELD -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:block"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-2160848846841372"
                 data-ad-slot="8166338640"
                 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
                <br />

                  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
           <!-- SHIELD -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:block"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-2160848846841372"
                 data-ad-slot="8166338640"
                 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>

                <br />
                  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
           <!-- SHIELD -->
            <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                 style="display:block"
                 data-ad-client="ca-pub-2160848846841372"
                 data-ad-slot="8166338640"
                 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside> <!-- Sidebar -->
</div>
```

This is my first time using google ads I went with the responsive ads since my site is using bootstrap.

### SCREEN SHOT

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjsKz.png)

Comment: can you add a screen shot?

Comment: To be able to help you, we need all the css files. BTW: you only have to include the adsbygoogle.js file once!